# Is there a way to extract the instance and static variables used in a method, to get an idea of which objects require to be mocked

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, junit4

I am developing JUnit test cases involving Mockito.

There are many cases where lots of instance and static variables being used in methods.

It is quite tedious to manually inspect all the lines of code in a method to get an idea of the objects which require to be mocked, for a high level understanding.

I wonder if there is any easier way to extract the instance and static variables used in methods.  I am also new to JUnit and Mockito.  Thanks.

Comment: **lots of instance and static variables being used in methods** , how many , on an average ? Also, by instance variable , do mean class level instance variable or method local object initialized with `new T()`?

Comment: @ Sabir Khan : 2 or 3 read-only static variables and 4 to 6 instance variables. All are class level variables.

Comment: @GhostCat The answer you provided is absolutely informative.  I appreciate and value your time.  I added my comments below your answer.  It will be very helpful to get to know a way to extract instance and static variables used in methods. Thanks.

Comment: You are very welcome ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are drawing the wrong conclusion.

You find that it is *hard* to write good unit tests for your production code - because it contains so many things that require to be mocked.

You want to fix that by somehow *automatically* mock everything that maybe prevents your production code from running in a unit test setup.

Wrong approach: you are trying to *work around* a **symptom**.

The root cause is most likely that you wrote *hard to test* production code. The answer is: spend your time and energy to learn how to write *easy to test* production code. Start with these [videos](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLD0011D00849E1B79) for example.

You see, any class or method that your production code contains should adhere the *single responsibility* principle. That alone drives you to production code that contains a *minimum* number of "external dependencies".

Beyond that: understand that using `static` is basically an abnormality in good OOP. Of course, it has its place - but as soon as "X is static" translates into "X breaks my unit tests" you are again, doing something wrong. Any usage of `static` that breaks your ability to unit test something is a clear indication that you should, again, *fix* your design.

Comment: I totally agree that the situation the OP describes indicates a sub-optimal design, and probably he is aware of that. He is not exactly asking for a solution to "automatically mock everything", but to "extract the instance and static variables used in methods", and this can as well be used as a quality indicator.

Comment: *It is quite tedious to manually inspect all the lines of code in a method to get an idea of the objects which require to be mocked* - I read that ... in the way I have written my answer. And so far, the OP hasn't given any further feedback. Rest assured: when OPs clarify their input, I have no problem throwing away 90% of my answer to match the changed input ;-)

Comment: @GhostCat : I agree that there are design issues and working on it. In fact the unit test cases end up cleaning the code. Thanks for the details and the reference to the collection of videos. The instance variables used in one method also are used in other methods. That is where the dependencies pile up. Thanks again for the answer! Any further inputs on the question will be helpful.